# sort and uniq csv files

Tags: sorting, duplicates, uniq

using linux commands,
I have a quoted csv file which I sorted by first column and then second column, now I  want to remove duplicates where they match in the first and second column, how can this be done?  uniq doesn't seem to be enough, or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse (rev) the file, then uniq ignoring the first N-2 fields (everything but the first two columns), then rev again.

```
rev | uniq -f N-2 -u | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I better understand what you need now. What about using awk?

> http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/62574-finding-duplicates-columns-removing-lines.html

Comment: May be a problem if there are *more than* 2 columns.

Comment: I already sorted the file, and uniq would not work on my problem constraint, I consider lines the same only if their first two columns are the same.

Comment: Yes, but `uniq` will consider the whole line, unless you tell it to consider only the first two fields. Something like @mjvotaw suggested